# Como eliminar una categoria en el eje X en ggballoonplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, studio

Tengo la siguiente grafica, sin embargo en el recuadro de la mitad y la derecha quisiera eliminar la categoria "naive mice" ya que este grupo solo tiene datos en el recuadro derecho. Como se puede hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido user294645 a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Primero que nada, no es una buena práctica "ocultar" una categoría simplemente por que esta no tiene datos, la falta de estos puede "decir" algo importante. Pero más allá de esto, te sugiero que compartas el código y una muestra de los datos, lo que se dice un [mcve] para que podamos ayudarte.